Change from macrocanonical ensamble to canonical ensamble, why it is possible?
Today my professor at lession derived the first correction to the ideal gas law in the case of bosons. He started by working in the grand canonical ensamble, obtaining the equation for the mean number of bosons $\frac{N\Lambda^3}{gV} = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{\zeta^n}{n^{\frac{3}{2}}}$. Then he introduced the density $\rho = \frac{N}{V}$ and said "let's now change to canonical ensamble and work with fixed density". I understand that in the canonical ensable N does not fluctuate, while in the grand canonical it does. In the end he found
\begin{equation}
   P_{bose} = \rho k_b T(1-\frac{\Lambda^3}{2^{5/2}g}\rho)
\end{equation}
I do not know how could we pass from grandcanonical to canonical, first deriving a result in the grandcanonical and then, to change the condition in which we are working (we needed constant density so canonical is the right ensamble) passing to canonical. Is it legit and why?

Why don't you ask your professor first? Have you checked any other sources (books, online notes)? We cannot understand what they did based on the two sentences in your question.

I should you are right. Anyway the problem, besides the specific application is: when can I start to work in an ensemble and than switch to another one in the middle of the calculation? My answer would be "when you are in the thermodynamic limit". Is it right?

I don't understand and I've never seen "switching ensembles in the middle of the calculation". But yes, at least for the usual textbook treatments of thermodynamics/statistical physics, you expect all ensembles to give the same results in the thermodynamic limit.

I could be more clear, sorry. The problem is that he found an equation for $\overline{N}$ and than said, let's change to the canonical ensamble, so he removed the mean. I guess this is because he was talking about the behaviour of a ideal gas with the first quantum correction, so the system is macroscopic...
